# r plot labels showing scaled value

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

[image]

My r code draws the above graph

```
p <- ggplot() +
     geom_point(data=data2, aes(x=df, y=dn, size=avgdice^3, fill = log2(tsSTDCommoncrawl)), shape=21)

p <- p + xlab("document fraction between commoncrawl and directcrawl") + 
    ylab("document number in commoncrawl") +
    labs(fill="timestamp \nvariance",size ="average \ndice value")
```

So the `size` and `fill` is scaled in the code. But I want the legends on the right side of the graph to show the original value of `avgdice` and `tsSTDCommoncrawl` instead of the `avgdice^3` and `log2(tsSTDCommoncrawl)` values.

Answer (score 0):

This will take two steps. You have to figure out where ggplot is putting the breaks, then enter them into a `scale` call manually. Let's use the iris dataset. I want to add another column with Sepal.Length cubed to emphasize differences in size:

```
example=iris
example$sizes=example$Sepal.Length^3
```

Now I can plot it:

```
gplot(example, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width))+
+   geom_point(aes(size=sizes))+
+   scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10))
```

[image]

The legend is putting breaks at 100, 200, 300, and 400. So I just need to take the cubed roots of those in the `scale` call, using `breaks` and `labels`:

```
> ggplot(example, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width))+
+   geom_point(aes(size=sizes))+
+   scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10), breaks=c(100, 200, 300, 400), labels=c(100, 200, 300, 400)^(1/3))
```

[image]

You can use a vector of text labels too, as long as the number of elements is equal to the number of breaks.